# Cablemodem frequent connection loss

Tags: connection, cable-modem

I have a Linksys BEFCMU10 cablemodem and a WRT54GL router with Tomato 1.27 firmware on Cox cable. My question is this: I get what seems to be random disconnects from the internet, where the cable modem lights are still normal, but I can connect nowhere, either via a url or an ip address. At the same time these disconnects are happening, I can go to the router's Tomato management webpage, and release/renew my external IP address from Cox's DHCP server. I've had Cox look at the signal levels on the cable modem, and they say they look fine. What brings back the modem, for sometimes as long as 17 days, is several power-cycles of the modem. I don't understand the underlying cable modem technology too well, but I do know that if I'm able to release/renew the DHCP-provided WAN address, I'd expect that the cable modem was working ok... Anybody have any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Cable modems work on a network/grid that connects to a T3 router running at 45 Megabits per second. Each area is a grid and this grid only has so many slots available. Depending on where you live, you could have a busy grid, or a not-so-busy one. My grid for example, was very busy; so I didnt get very good performance and I had the same problems as you. (ie.. when the slots in the grid are full, a cycle is required which should put you back with the active users.  The problem lies with the cable companies' lack of upgrades to their equipment to meet the needs of the consumer. There isn't much you can do besides maybe write angry letters or switch to DSL which has slower speeds.

Comment: My immediate nextdoor neighbor has Embarq/Century DSL and it is slooooowww... I have an arrangement with him to allow me to use his wifi when my cable modem is down, and he can use my wifi when his dsl is down... so far, it's been me on his system everytime and he's never *had* to use mine... Other than the slower speed, I guess DSL is a bit more stable than Cox cable...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue for months but finally solved it as I have **not experienced a single connection loss since** I did this.:

**Locate** any and all of the **unused coaxial cable outlets** that you have starting from the main cable running from outside, and including any unused connections of **splitters** that may be tucked away in crawl space or otherwise.
Then **make sure** all of these ends are either **connected to a device** or have a [**75ohm coaxial terminator cap**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VWHX2FS) on them.

**Every open end** that is connected to the same line as your cable modem will be **reflecting the signals** back and this is becomes a major issue with the more recent types of signals used by ISPs to provide higher throughput, as they use a much higher frequency, and as such are very sensitive to **interference**.

If you don't have the terminator caps on hand(does anyone really?), you can also use just about **any old device** you might have that uses a cable connection. The most likely of these are **old cable modems**(earlier than DOCSIS 3.1) or **TVs/cable TV boxes**, which should absorb the signal the same as the terminator cap would or better, and these **don't need to be powered** so just run the shortest coax cable you have on hand between the outlet and device and hide it away behind some furniture.

Power strips, surge protectors, and UPS that feature a coaxial inlet+outlet might be useable as well, but I am not certain they will properly absorb the signal without something connected to the opposite side.

[This video convinced me to try this after the idea of the interference came up in conversation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S_YaRvlAic)